# Unable to delete a sharepoint designer 2013 workflow from the interface

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I get no error messages but I am unable to delete them. They look 'empty' as in the actions contained but the delete button does not have any effect on them.

The environment is sharepoint online and the workflow is a list workflow based on an existing list that is live and working

Comment: Did you create the workflows in SharePoint Designer 2013?  Sometimes OOTB workflows are deployed as 2010 workflows and the only way to delete them is in the UI not in SharePoint Designer.

Comment: I have created those workflows in SP designer using the template of 2013. I can delete the ones with the 2010 template fine

Answer (score 0):

the only reason that seems a possibility is , whether you have necessary permissions

Since you are mentioning that there are no errors, and are empty.

What actions are actually available in the workflow ?

Comment: I am admin of o365 and obviously site collection admin of the site in talk. The actions were very easy such as create item in another list but now i have deleted them